# How to sort groupby and filter using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a code like this:

```
grouped=L2014.groupby(['state','NAME'])
grouped.mask.value_counts(normalize=True,).sort_index()
```

results like this:

```
state  NAME           mask 
CO     Adams          False    0.407195
                      True     0.592805
       Alamosa        False    1.000000
       Arapahoe       False    0.460602
                      True     0.539398
       Archuleta      False    1.000000
```

How to sort the numbers by the top biggest 5 True value? and return it?
like how to show the group by by the descending of true value.

updated
after try :

```
grouped.mask.value_counts(normalize=1).sort_index(level=2,ascending=False)
```

results is

```
state  NAME               mask 
TX     Zavala             True     0.057416
   Zapata             True     0.042623
   Young              True     0.928009
   Yoakum             True     0.886719
   Wood               True     0.604720
   Wise               True     0.859006
   Wilson             True     0.704336
   Williamson         True     0.269555
   Wilbarger          True     0.317355
   Wichita            True     0.067734
   Wheeler            True     0.992218
   Wharton            True     0.298335
   Webb               True     0.465170
   Washington         True     0.391229
   Ward               True     0.269036
   Waller             True     0.145650
   Walker             True     0.580991
   Victoria           True     0.076246
   Van Zandt          True     0.357858
   Val Verde          True     0.551620
   Uvalde             True     0.465817
   Upton              True     0.900000
   Upshur             True     0.595388
   Tyler              True     0.119469
   Trinity            True     0.215548
   Travis             True     0.684808
```

As you can see, the true value is still not sorted from largest to smallest, and i only want top 5 values(5 NAME) for each state .

Updated:

After try:

```
 L2014.groupby(['state','NAME']).mask.value_counts(normalize=True).filter(like='True', axis=0).nlargest(2000)
```

i get like this :

```
state  NAME             mask

 NE     Furnas           True    1.000000
OK     Washita          True    1.000000
TX     Hall             True    1.000000
SD     Fall River       True    1.000000
TX     Throckmorton     True    1.000000
KY     Hamilton         True    1.000000
IA     Hancock          True    1.000000
SD     Bennett          True    1.000000
TX     Stonewall        True    1.000000
       Carson           True    1.000000
SD     Adams            True    1.000000
OK     Sebastian        True    1.000000
TX     McCurtain        True    1.000000
       Gray             True    1.000000
OK     Roger Mills      True    1.000000
TX     Childress        True    1.000000
       Reagan           True    1.000000
KY     Pittsylvania     True    1.000000
TX     Ochiltree        True    1.000000
       Motley           True    1.000000
       Collingsworth    True    1.000000
OK     Harmon           True    1.000000
KY     Buchanan         True    1.000000
KS     Woodson          True    1.000000
       Wilson           True    1.000000
       Wichita          True    1.000000
TX     Hartley          True    1.000000
KS     Cloud            True    1.000000
       Decatur          True    1.000000
       Elk              True    1.000000
IA     Taylor           True    1.000000
```

it does group by state any more.
thank you

Comment: You should show output as well for clarity.

Comment: The output is shown as above

Comment: Please post a sample input data set and desired output (based on your sample input data set). I'm pretty sure - you would have an answer within a couple of minutes if you would give people a possibility to test their solution... [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: its clear enough. do not know how else i should add

Comment: do you want to have an answer, that will work for your data or just some answer? ;)

Comment: what i needed is only display the biggest top five True value according to group by state and name.

Comment: simply use [this technique](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html#top-n-rows-per-group)

Comment: not working.too baddddddddddddddddd

Comment: then try one of [those](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36702926/5741205) ...

Comment: can not use  df.sort_values(by=['manager_id', 'dep'], ascending=[False,True]).head(5) because it a dataframe groupby not a df directly. So when i try sort_values,it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grouped.mask.value_counts(normalize=1).sort_index(level=2,ascending=False).filter(like='True', axis=0).nlargest(5)
```

or

```
grouped.mask.value_counts(normalize=1).filter(like='True', axis=0).nlargest(5)
```

Comment: It still not the results i wanted. When i try you just suggested, it give me :                                                                                                                    state  NAME     mask
     CO     Chase    True    1.0
    IA     Hancock  True    1.0
           Taylor   True    1.0
    KS     Cloud    True    1.0
           Decatur  True    1.0

Comment: I tried your line to code, it only give the upper 5 results, not show me the results of by state and NAME. It only show N records on the top.