# Getting Top N results from pandas groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a two columns in dataset:

1) Supplier_code

2) Item_code

I have grouped them using:

```
data.groupby(['supplier_code', 'item_code']).size()
```

I get result like this:

```
supplier_code  item_code
591495         127018419     9
               547173046     1
3024466        498370473     1
               737511044     1
               941755892     1
6155238        875189969     1
13672569       53152664      1
               430351453     1
               573603000     1
               634275342     1
18510135       362522958     6
               405196476     6
               441901484    12
29222428       979575973     1
31381089       28119319      2
               468441742     3
               648079349    18
               941387936     1
```

I have my top 15 suppliers using:

```
supCounter = collections.Counter(datalist[3])
supDic = dict(sorted(supCounter.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:15]) 
print supDic.keys()
```

This is my list of top 15 suppliers:

```
[723223131, 687164888, 594473706, 332379250, 203288669, 604236177, 
533512754, 503134099, 982883317, 147405879, 151212120, 737780569, 561901243, 
786265866, 79886783]
```

Now I want to join the two, i.e. groupby and get only the top 15 suppliers and there item counts.

Kindly help me in figuring this out.

Comment: Can you provide us with a [mcve], so I can reproduce your groupby and clearly understand what it is you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can `groupby` `supplier_code` and then `sum` and `sort_values`. Take the top 15 and you're done.

For example, with:

```
gb_size = data.groupby(['supplier_code', 'item_code']).size()
```

Then:

```
N = 3 # change to 15 for actual data
gb_size.groupby("supplier_code").sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(N)
```

Output:

```
supplier_code
31381089    24
18510135    24
591495      10
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ok, and if you want the rows from the output of the groupby corresponding to those supplier_codes, then `gb_size.loc[gb_size.sum(level=0).sort_values(ascending=False).head(3).index.values]`

Comment: `sum(level=0)` is a little cleaner than my solution, good idea.

Comment: Check this detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702904/pandas-top-n-rows-top-n-rows-per-group-equivalent-for-row-number-overpartiti